# Dropzone.js - Is it possible to mantain the uploaded files for display after postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dropzone.js

I have a web forms asp.net application and i'm making a file upload page that uses dropzone.js, the problem is that I want the uploaded files to stay visible after the page postback since I have some radiobuttons and buttons that I need.

The uploaded files are avaibile server side but I wanted to know if there was a way to keep them visible in the dropzone